# Laravel Task Scheduling where stores?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel has [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling) where events, job and commands can be scheduled. I just can't figure out where does it store them? It doesn't look like it stores it in database

Comment: Looking at that link they're "stored" in code are they not?

Comment: *"Your task schedule is defined in the app/Console/Kernel.php file's schedule method."*

Comment: Are you familiar with doubly linked list in C language ? where we can make a queue and we can change each node position, I think in the same manner scheduling works.

Comment: @ianinn They are defined there as `$schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();` where does it actually stored that it run every hour. @C2484 no I will read on that. Does php has same?

Comment: @user256968 The code *is* the configuration; the call to `hourly()` means that it will only run every hour. The Laravel scheduler setup requires that you trigger the scheduler every minute - it then checks whether each configured job matches the current time, and either runs it or ignores it.

Answer (score -1):

Your batch jobs can be stored in a database table, then use the scheduler to execute it. 
The function below can be put in `app/console/Kernel.php`

```
    $schedule->call(function () {
        //put your logic here e.g. send verification code to newly 
        //registered users at 10 pm
        })->dailyAt('22:00');
```

To execute the scheduler, you must specify the name of the command:

```
  protected $commands = [
    send:email
];
```

Then you would call it in terminal as `php artisan send:email` and keep the terminal process running.

Or you can setup a [cron job](https://scotch.io/@Kidalikevin/how-to-set-up-cron-job-in-laravel)